# How to initialize thread local class variables dynamically?

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, thread-local

I have code like this:

```
template<int A, class Super>
class Child : public Super {
    ..
    static __thread void *ptr;
};
// Initialization
__thread void *Child<A, Super>::ptr = NULL;
```

Instead, I need to initialize `ptr` as:

```
ptr = Super::func(Size);
```

At first, I was doing this assignment in the constructor, but as new threads were created, their `ptr` were `NULL`(as they should be). So presently, I am checking if `ptr` is `NULL` and if so assigning it my way. Is there any better way to do so?

Comment: what is the meaning of "better"?

Comment: Presently, I am having an 'if' statement before every time I am accessing `ptr`. However, per thread, I only have to initialize it once. By better I mean a solution where I could initialize ptr just once(for every thread) and use it directly. My initialization code is dependent on 'Super' and 'Size' so I can't do that in the static initialization

Comment: What is stopping you from simply initializing `ptr` with the desired value at the beginning of each thread? If a thread wants to use `Child` objects, it should initialize `Child` properly beforehand.

Comment: The problem is that this code is part of a library. I am initializing Child's object within the library itself. The software using this library will be spawning threads. Is there some kind of thread event that I should catch to initialize `ptr`?